# Cannot add react to a web page

Tags: html, javascript, web

I'm trying to add react js to a basic web page. This is the file structure:

```
////
├─index.html
└─js/
  ├─Page.js
  └─index.js
```

`index.html`:

```
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/index.js" type="text/babel"> </script>
</body>
```

`index.js`:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Page from './Page';

ReactDOM.render(<Page />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

`Page.js`:

```
import {Component} from 'react'

class Page extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        )
    }
}

export default Page;
```

For some reason `Hello World` doesn't appear on the page when I open `index.html`. How can I fix this page?

Answer (score 1):

In your `index.js` you should `import React` as your component will transpile with Babel to `React.createElement('h1', null, 'hello world')`

Comment: I'm not using webpack.  Would `import` work in an old school webpage.